# SSH proxy tunnel not accessing blocked sites on Windows 10 and 11 due to DNS leak?

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, windows-firewall

I have a problem with an SSH proxy. On my Mac, I used the command `ssh -D 8080 root@my.server.ip` to login to my server, and I set the Mac SOCKS proxy settings to use `127.0.0.1:8080`, and it was working fine to access websites that would have been otherwise blocked on my network.

However, I could not get it to unblock websites on Windows using the built-in OpenSSH client (entering the exact same command) or (in another try) PuTTY, even after allowing port 8080 through the Windows Firewall and trying both the system proxy settings and the Firefox proxy settings.

Could you give me a hint on why it is not working? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out why it wasn't working and a partial solution:

When using SSH proxying to bypass websites that are blocked by DNS filtering, the DNS requests might not go through the proxy, causing a DNS leak and making the DNS requests go to the censoring DNS server. To check if there are leaks, go to https://ipleak.net/.

To fix the problem when using Firefox's proxy settings, make sure to check "Proxy DNS when using SOCKS v5".

If you want *all* programs to use the proxied DNS on Windows, it might be a little bit harder. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32082423/dns-through-socks-proxy-how-do-i-change-windows-settings-for-domain-resolution) suggests running your own DNS server that forwards your DNS requests through a proxy. If anyone has an easier method, please let me know, and I will update this answer.